# Lista en un while true es modificado?

Tags: c#, lista, task

```
    static List<string> nombres = new List<string>();

    public static void ParalelLoop()
    {
      while(true)
        foreach (var s in nombres)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(s);
        }
    }

    static void Main()
    {
        var task = new Task(() =>
        {
            ParalelLoop();
        });
        task.Start();
        nombres.Add("nuevo Elemento");
    }
```

Si voy añadiendo cosas en nombre la lista se actualizara y escribira el nuevo elemento? o debo parar el task añadirlo y empezarlo devuelta?

Comment: ¿Qué problema tienes con el código mostrado? ¿Qué es lo que deseas lograr?

Comment: hay algun caso borde el cual deberia tener en cuenta? tipo si voy añadiendo mas elementos o quitando

Comment: ¿cual es la funcionalidad o requerimiento para esto? Como te comentan no se puede iterar o detectar con Collection que cambio. Mas que nada no se puede iterar y modificar al mismo tiempo con dicha coleccion. Pero existen dos posibilidades [ObservableCollection<T>](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.objectmodel.observablecollection-1) y tambien las [colecciones o estructura de datos preparadas para  entornos de programacion paralela](https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/data-structures-for-parallel-programming).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No es posible modificar una lista y recorrerla al mismo tiempo.

Lo que puedes hacer es

```
while(true)
 foreach (var s in nombres.ToArray())
 {
   Console.WriteLine(s);
 }
```

De esta manera recorre una copia de la lista original.

Comment: Me sirvio la idea de crear una copia ya que necesito que la linea se ejecute todo el rato, a diferencia de las propuestas de ObservableCollection y ConcurrentBang que requieren iniciar solo cuando es modificada.

Answer (score 2):

Como te comentan no se puede iterar o detectar con [Collection](https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/collections) "simple" que fue modificandose, . Mas que nada no se puede iterar y modificar al mismo tiempo con dicha coleccion o tipo de estructura para ser mas general. Porque tienes que prevenir que se pueda "escribir" al mismo tiempo que se recorre mas que nada en multiples hilos.

Pero existen dos posibilidades que se me ocurren, puedes darle un vista

- **OPCION 1:** [ObservableCollection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.objectmodel.observablecollection-1)
- **OPCION 2:** [colecciones o estructura de datos preparadas para  entornos de programacion paralela](https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/data-structures-for-parallel-programming) en un ejemplo con [ConcurrentBag](https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.collections.concurrent.concurrentbag-1?view=net-6.0) pero hay varios

Las dos me parece que te podrian ayudar, pero tendrias que probar o testear (dejo unos enlaces repo con un simple ejemplo)

Vamos uno por uno

**OPCION 1:** [ObservableCollection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.objectmodel.observablecollection-1)

Aquí la idea es "detectar" cuando se modifico la coleccion o sufrio cambio, pero "durante" el recorrido deberias bloquear este tipo de cambio con algun bloqueo
Dejo un ejemplo por aqui

- https://github.com/fernandezja/net6-experiments/tree/main/012-observable-collection

  ```
  var oc = new ObservableCollection<string>
  {
      "a",
      "b"
  };

  for (int index = 1; index <= 5; index++)
  {
      oc.Add(index.ToString());
  }

  void Printer() {
      foreach (var item in oc)
      {
          Console.WriteLine(item);
      }
  }

  oc.CollectionChanged += Oc_CollectionChanged;

  void Oc_CollectionChanged(object? sender, System.Collections.Specialized.NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
  {
      Console.WriteLine("Oc_CollectionChanged...");
      Printer();
  }

  while (true)
  {
      Console.Write("Add new item:");
      var newItem = Console.ReadLine();
      if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(newItem))
      {
          oc.Add(newItem);
      }
  }
  ```

**OPCION 2:** [colecciones o estructura de datos preparadas para  entornos de programacion paralela](https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/data-structures-for-parallel-programming) en un ejemplo con [ConcurrentBag](https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.collections.concurrent.concurrentbag-1?view=net-6.0) pero hay varios

Textual de Microsoft Learn:

> En .NET Framework 4 y versiones posteriores, las colecciones del espacio de nombres System.Collections.Concurrent proporcionan operaciones eficaces y seguras para subprocesos con el fin de acceder a los elementos de la colección desde varios subprocesos.

Aqui tomamos como ejemplo  [ConcurrentBag](https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.collections.concurrent.concurrentbag-1?view=net-6.0), dejo el ejemplo completo en

- https://github.com/fernandezja/net6-experiments/tree/main/013-concurrentbag

La idea es la misma que estabas escribiendo, en un hilo tienes el codigo para escribir y en otro para ir "recorriendo", o incluso teniando una estrategia de recorrido. Pero siempre depende de lo que necesites o requierimientos

```
        ConcurrentBag<int> bag = new ConcurrentBag<int>();


    Task t1 = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
    {
        Random random = new Random();
        for (int i = 1; i < 11; ++i)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"[Task1] (1 to 10) Add {i}");
            bag.Add(i);
            Thread.Sleep(random.Next(20, 300));
        }
    });


    Task t2 = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
    {
        Random random = new Random();
        for (int i = 11; i < 21; ++i)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"[Task2] (11 to 20) Add {i}");
            bag.Add(i);
            Thread.Sleep(random.Next(20, 300));
        }
    });


    Task t3 = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
    {
        Random random = new Random();
        for (int i = 21; i < 31; ++i)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"[Task3] (21 to 30) Add {i}");
            bag.Add(i);
            Thread.Sleep(random.Next(20, 300));
        }
    });



    Task t4 = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
    {
        Random random = new Random();
        int i = 0;
        while (i != 4)
        {
            foreach (var item in bag)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(i + "-" + item);
                Thread.Sleep(random.Next(20, 300));
            }
            i++;
            Thread.Sleep(random.Next(20, 300));
        }

    });


    Task.WaitAll(t1, t2, t3, t4);
```

Espero que te sirva de ayuda o guia